# $d(E_n,E_m)>0 \forall n \neq m$, and $f|_{E_k}$ is constant. Then $f|_{\cup E_k}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Given a function $f:E\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and *finite* (see edit) collection $\{E_k\} \subseteq E$ of disjoint sets and $d(E_n,E_m)>0 \forall n \neq m$, and $f|_{E_k}$ is
constant. Then $f|_{\cup E_k}$ is continuous.

This fact is used in the proof of Lusin's theorem, but I can't see why $f$ must be continuous on the whole union. I would like an explanation of this step on the proof (I would be specially happy if presented a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of this continuity, because this is what I'm more confortable with)

The whole proof can be found [here](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eheil/6337/spring11/lusin.pdf).

Edit: I don't know if this edit is under the rules of math.stackexchange, but since it was pointed out in the answer, I wrote countable collection instead of finite collection, which is what I aimed for explanation on what I did not understood, so I edited the question to finite collection, because I still wnat to see an explanation of it and it doesn't feel right to create a new question about this. If this edit is not under the rules, please forgive me and feel free to unedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is false as you have stated it.

Let $E_0=\{0\}$, for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $E_n=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$; clearly $d(E_n,E_m)>0$ whenever $n\ne m$. Let $E=\bigcup_{n\ge 0}E_n$, and define

$$f:E\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in E\setminus E_0\\
1,&\text{if }x=0\,.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $f$ is constant on each $E_n$, but $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks! This means that I understood even less of the proof of Lusin's Theorem :( . Do you know what is lacking on my hypothesis for this to hold, as it was used in the Lusin's Theorem proof?

Comment: @user1618: When it was used at the beginning of the proof, there were only finitely many sets $E_k$, and in that case it’s easy to prove, since each $E_k$ has an open nbhd disjoint from all of the others. I didn’t dig through the rest of the proof to see whether it was used later with infinitely many $E_k$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Could you please check if this proof of the statement is correct?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $x \in \cup E_k$, then $x \in E_{k_0}$ some of the $k_0$. Define $\delta = \min_k \{ d(E_{k_0},E_k)\} > 0$. Then, if $|x-y| < \delta$, they are both in $E_{k_0}$, but $f$ is constant there, so $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @user1618: You need to specify that the minimum is over $k\ne k_0$, but otherwise it’s okay.